# Terminating with uncaught NSException

Tags: ios

```
2015-01-25 17:09:31.413 Self Diagnosis[11115:563430] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main_iPhone' in bundle NSBundle </Users/rajeevgodse/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/60EAC167-7EE5-4AE7-9E6E-590ECC47C8E6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/04EBD1D7-39B1-4E60-BAA2-1A1B6B8B1EED/Self Diagnosis.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01ca1df6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0192ba97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   UIKit                               0x0092b768 -[UIStoryboard name] + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x003153f2 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 53
    4   UIKit                               0x00315694 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245
    5   UIKit                               0x0031403f -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1337
    6   UIKit                               0x0032cd30 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
    7   UIKit                               0x00312d7f -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
    8   FrontBoardServices                  0x036029de __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
    9   FrontBoardServices                  0x0360246f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
    10  FrontBoardServices                  0x03614425 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 26
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x01bc57a0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x01bbb0b3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x01bba818 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x01bba1ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x01bb9fdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    16  UIKit                               0x00312744 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
    17  UIKit                               0x00315e16 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    18  Self Diagnosis                      0x0005d03d main + 141
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x02274ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I keep getting this error.  I've seen all the other questions, but I can't figure out how to solve my error.
Please help me.  I need an answer by tomorrow.

Comment: `[...] reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main_iPhone' in bundle NSBundle [...]` Couldn't be more obvious?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the error is just in front of you.
*Could not find a storyboard named 'Main_iPhone' in bundle NSBundle*

- Have you got a storyboard with that name?
- If yes, is it added to the target you are working on?

Comment: Sorry, @Robert, I'm a bit of a beginner.  I do have a file named Main_iPhone.storyboard.  How can I see if it is added to the target that I am working on?

Comment: I added Main_iPhone.storyboard to Copy Bundle Resources in Build Phase.  It worked, but it was written in red

Comment: It's fine if it shows up in red. It does the same in my projects. If it built fine, that all that matters.